# Pandas replace all items in a row with NaN if one value is NaN

Tags: python, pandas

I want to get rid of some records with NaNs. This works perfectly:

```
df.dropna(axis=0, how='any',inplace=True)
```

However, it changes the shape of my dataframe, and the index is no longer uniformly spaced. Therefore, I'd like to replace all items in these rows with `np.nan`. Is there a simple way to do this?

I was thinking about resampling the dataframe after `dropna`, but that only seems to work with a prescribed interval, whereas I would rather use the original index. Another approach would be to loop over the dataframe with `iterrows`, but that also feels cumbersome.

Comment: If the problem is the change of your index, you just have to reset it right?
df = df.reset_index(drop = True)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The command below selects all rows with any value equal to Nan, and assigns NaNs to the rest of those rows.

```
df.loc[df.isnull().any(axis=1), :] = np.nan
```

Answer (score 1):

using this code also works without slicing`df = df.replace('nan',np.nan)`